# How to fetch a column from a Json format array in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, getjson

Suppose i have a array like:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json as simplejson
import random

def getUserInfo(request, user_index):
    data= "[{\"index\":\"1\",\"username\":\"a\",\"fname\":\"a\",\"lname\":\"a\",\"email\":\"a1@xyz.com\",\"sysadmin\":true},{\"index\":\"2\",\"username\":\"ab\",\"fname\":\"ab\",\"lname\":\"ab\",\"email\":\"ab1@xyz.com\",\"sysadmin\":false}]";

    result = <something>(data)

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), content_type = "application/json")
```

for suppose user_index = 1
what to write in 
result = something? (data)?
so that i will get the result as

result =

```
{\"index\":\"1\",\"username\":\"a\",\"fname\":\"a\",\"lname\":\"a\",\"email\":\"a1@xyz.com\",\"sysadmin\":true}
```

Comment: Your `data` is already a JSON-encoded string. Why are you calling `dumps`? That's just going to get you a JSON-encoded JSON-encoded string. You probably want `loads` in there somewhere. Or maybe you want `data` to be a list of dicts, rather than a JSON representation of a list of dicts, in the first place?

Comment: Actually my requirement for the response is that.

Comment: Your requirement for the response is the JSON representation of a string which is itself a JSON representation of a list of dicts? If so, there's almost certainly something wrong with the code on the other side of this—if someone else on your team is writing the Ajax code while you write the Django code, you should go slap him until he fixes it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the dictionary where index = 1...

```
import json

data = "[{\"index\":\"1\",\"username\":\"a\",\"fname\":\"a\",\"lname\":\"a\",\"email\":\"a1@xyz.com\",\"sysadmin\":true},{\"index\":\"2\",\"username\":\"ab\",\"fname\":\"ab\",\"lname\":\"ab\",\"email\":\"ab1@xyz.com\",\"sysadmin\":false}]";
data = json.loads(data)

for i in xrange(len(data)):
    if data[i].get('index') == "1":
        print data[i]
```

Please note that your index is a string, and not an integer

Comment: Thanks it worked with a little custom modification to my code.